# How to return a value from a async function in array.map in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to return the value from an async function in the array.map I am trying to access the value from them but I am getting Array `[[object Promise], [object Promise], [object Promise], [object Promise]]`?

I want async inside the `array1.map` because I have some process that takes time so I need to use await.

```
var array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const test = async ()=>{
const map1 = await array1.map(async x => 'hi');

return map1;
// expected output: Array [2, 8, 18, 32]
}
test().then((data)=>{
console.log(data)
})
```

expected output: Array `['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi']`
my output: `[[object Promise], [object Promise], [object Promise], [object Promise]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` function, where you put your array of promises

```js
var array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const test = async () => {
  const map1 = await Promise.all(array1.map(async x => 'hi'));
  return map1;
}

test().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

> expected output: Array ['hi', 'hi', 'hi', 'hi']

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

If you put await inside the map higher order function you will get expected result

```
var array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

// pass a function to map
const test = async () => {
  const map1 = await Promise.all(array1.map( async x =>await  'hi'));
  return map1;
}

test().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Solution 2

If you remove async from the higher order function parameter you will get the expected output .

var array1 = [1, 4, 9, 16];

```
// pass a function to map
const test = async () => {
  const map1 = await Promise.all(array1.map( x => 'hi'));
  return map1;
}

test().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Thank you solution1 works for my case because I have some async functions inside the array.map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async.map from the [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) module. async.map function takes three arguments.

1. Array to iterate over.
2. Function to be executed for each item from the array.
3. Callback to be executed after all iterations are done.